# Applying for Schengen Visa after (German) Student visa expires IN Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, germany, study

I am a Indian national (***not eligible for 90-days visa free program***) spending a semester in Germany on a German Student Visa right now. My student visa expires in the third week of December, but I want to spend Christmas in Germany. I was wondering how and where could I apply for a Schengen tourist visa here in Germany for that one week I want to spend here? I was told there is a possibility to renew the visa but its only available if theres a change in course/ or during general emergency, and clearly I am not eligible for that(?!).

I read a few questions here but it was mostly by people who already have the 90 days visa free program, which they could use to re-enter Schengen area after their student/resident visa expires without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Auswärtiges Amt, it would seem that your only course of action is to ask at the "foreigners authority" of the federal state in which you are studying (emphasis added):

> [...] visa applications must be approved by the relevant foreigners authority in Germany, i.e. the foreigners authority in the place where the applicant intends to take up residence. If the approval of the foreigners authority is necessary before a visa can be issued, the procedure can take up to three months, in some cases longer, since the foreigners authority will often consult other authorities (e.g. the Federal Employment Agency). Missions may only issue visas once they have obtained the approval of the foreigners authority.
>
> [...]
>
> **The foreigners authorities are also responsible for measures and decisions pertaining to residence law for foreigners already residing in Germany.** Foreigners authorities are not subordinate agencies of the Federal Foreign Office, and the Federal Foreign Office cannot influence their decisions. They are in fact accountable to and operate under the supervision of the respective interior ministries and senators of the Länder (federal states).

Source: http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/EN/EinreiseUndAufenthalt/Visabestimmungen_node.html#doc480844bodyText7

Unfortunately, I am unable to find any information on the internet to indicate whether they would receive your request favorably, which perhaps implies that they will not.  Please let us know how it turns out.